# How to solve perpetual reload of component with three useEffects in React 18?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on upgrading the libraries of an application. It was previously running in React 17. After upgrading to React 18 a component started reloading in infinity whereas before it ran correctly. When running React 18 in strict mode the isMounted.current is always false.

```
const useTimesheetHeaderActions = ({ onSuccess, onError, shouldNotify = true } = {}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const refresh = useRefresh();
  const notify = useNotify();

  const isMounted = useRef(true); // flag telling if component is mounted

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
      // flag on unmount. Checking this prevents running code on an umounted component. Tricks in Ludo
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // this useEffect notifies errors, trigggers onError callback and resets state
    if (state.error && state.error.length > 0 && isMounted.current) {
      if (shouldNotify) {
        handleNotify(state, notify);
      } // notify feedback
      if (onError) {
        onError(state.currentAction, state.error);
      }
      // log error to logging service
      logger.error(`timesheetheader action "${state.currentAction.type}" encountered error`, state);
      // clear error after its reported to avoid double callbacks
      dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.RESET }); // ready for new actions
    }
  }, [state, notify, dispatch, onError, shouldNotify]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this useEffect notifies success and resets state
    if (state.success && isMounted.current) {
      if (shouldNotify) {
        handleNotify(state, notify);
      } // notify feedback
      dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.RESET }); // ready for new actions
    }
  }, [state, notify, dispatch, shouldNotify]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this effect handles actions
    if (isMounted.current) {
      const onAction = async (currentAction) => {
        try {
          const res = await handleAction(currentAction, navigate, location);

          if (!isMounted.current) {
            /* if navigating in handleAction, component is unmounted and we should
             * cancel all active subscriptions
             */
            return;
          }
          if (res && res.errors && res.errors.length > 0) {
            // handle graphQl errors
            dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.ERROR, payload: res.errors });
            return;
          }

          dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.SUCCESS, payload: true });
          refresh(); // things have changed, make them visible

          if (onSuccess) {
            onSuccess(currentAction, res); // onSuccess is placed here to access res
            // should be last in que as comp could unmount in onSuccess callback
          }
        } catch (e) {
          dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.ERROR, payload: [e] });
        }
      };

      if (state.currentAction && state.ready && !state.error) {
        // !READY blocks actions to trigger multiple times until RESET is called
        dispatch({ type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.READY, payload: false });
        onAction(state.currentAction);
      }
    }
  }, [state, dispatch, onSuccess, refresh, navigate, location]);

  return [dispatch, TIMESHEET_HEADER_ACTIONS, state]; // returns valid actions
};

export default useTimesheetHeaderActions;
```

the component above is called by:

```
const VerticalTimeSheetHeaderMenu = ({
  successCallback,
  isVertical,
  actions,
  open,
  id,
  flowStatus,
  isAwaitingControl,
  onClose,
  isOnHold,
  permissions,
  setDisabled,
  projectId,
  reportName,
  redirectAfterDelete,
  addedBySupplierId,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const translate = useTranslate();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const notify = useNotify();
  const [deleteDialogOpen, setDeleteDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [commentDialogOpen, setCommentDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [creditDialogOpen, setCreditDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [disapproveDialogOpen, setDisapproveDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [commentText, setCommentText] = useState('');
  const [creditSupplier, setCreditSupplier] = useState(true);
  const [creditCommentText, setCreditCommentText] = useState('');
  const [duplicateDialogOpen, setDuplicateDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [allowedActions, setAllowedActions] = useState(actions);

  const featureToggles = useContext(FeaturesContext);

  const { theme } = useSelector(selectTheme);

  const handleSuccess = ({ type }) => {
    if (successCallback) {
      successCallback(type);
    }
    if (redirectAfterDelete && type === TIMESHEET_HEADER_ACTIONS.DELETE) {
      navigate(-1);
    }
    onClose();
  };

  const [
    dispatch,
    {
      OPEN,
      EDIT,
      DELETE,
      DUPLICATE,
      ONHOLD,
      ACTIVATE,
      APPROVE,
      DISAPPROVE,
      COMMENT,
      CREDIT,
      DEACTIVATE,
      RETURN,
      RETURN_TO_SUPPLIER,
      REPORT,
      SEND_TO_CONTROL,
    },
  ] = useTimesheetHeaderActions({ onSuccess: handleSuccess, onError: onClose });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!allowedActions) {
      return;
    }
    // check if any actions are allowed
    const hasAnyAction =
      allowedActions && Object.keys(allowedActions).some((key) => allowedActions[key]);

    if (!hasAnyAction && setDisabled) {
      // no actions are allowed - disable menu
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [allowedActions, setDisabled]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!permissions || !flowStatus) {
      // do nothing until dependencies are updated
      return;
    }

    if (!actions) {
      const calculatedActions = getAllowedTimesheetActions({
        flowStatus,
        isAwaitingControl,
        permissions,
        featureToggles,
        addedBySupplierId,
      });
      setAllowedActions(calculatedActions); // update actions when timesheet changes
    }
    if (actions) {
      setAllowedActions(actions); // update actions when timesheet changes
    }
  }, [featureToggles, permissions, flowStatus, actions, isAwaitingControl, addedBySupplierId]);

  if (!allowedActions) {
    return null;
  }

  const MenuWrapper = isVertical ? Menu : Toolbar;
  const horizontalMenuItemStyles =
    theme === 'dark' ? styles.action_item_horizontal_dark : styles.action_item_horizontal_light;
  const menuItemStyles = isVertical ? styles.action_item_vertical : horizontalMenuItemStyles;

  return (
    <MenuWrapper
      className={
        isVertical
          ? clsx(`theme-${theme}`, styles.vertical_menu)
          : clsx(`theme-${theme}`, styles.toolbar)
      }
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      {...rest}
    >
      {allowedActions[OPEN] && (
        <MenuItem
          className={menuItemStyles}
          onClick={() => dispatch({ type: OPEN, payload: { projectId, id } })}
        >
          <SubjectIcon /> {translate('resources.TimeSheetHeader.buttons.open')}
        </MenuItem>
      )}
    // some more code in the return statement below. Just several other menu-items with a dispatch function
}
```

I tried to remove the useLayoutEffect but that did not change anything. I also tried to set isMounted.current = false as a return statement of the last useEffect. I am pretty new to useReducer so any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask you to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to help narrow down the problem and minimize what potential answerers have to wade through?